# application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not being called

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm working with push notifications. I read through Apple's programming guide that in case of Remote or Local notifications, application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called and hold the payload in the launchOptions. From there in case of notifications I can respond to the push. I'm testing push on two devices. One that issues the push and the second receives it. I ran the app on both devices and i kept one turned on and the second exited the app to home screen and closed the phone to wait for a notification (i didn't close the app on xcode though). I issues a push and i received it on the receiver device, however using NSLog, it seems that application:didFinishLaunchWithOptions is not being called when the push is opened and only once at application first start. I didn't provide code because there no much added to test that other than the push which is working fine. What could be wrong? is that the right way to respond to notifications opened when the app is in the background?

Answer (score 3):

If you just close the app by pressing the home button the application does not actually launch again so `application:didFinishLaunchWithOptions` won't be called the second time

Instead, what will be called is `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` and `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` so i'd recommend handling whatever is necessary in `applicationDidBecomeActive`as that method is called when opening the app & coming back into the foreground.

Comment: okay thanks. but how am i able to get the notification payload(data) from either of the functions you mentioned above?

Comment: Check @Eran s answer for parsing the notification. The payload is within the userInfo dictionary that is passed to that method

Answer (score 2):

If your app is running in the background (or in the foreground) when the push notification arrives, the method that gets the notification payload is `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`.